# Channel form: "The selected author is invalid"

Tags: channel-form

When trying to update the status of an entry through channel form, I get an error that says "The selected author is invalid".

Just do be sure it's not a permissions problem due to lack of permissions for the user group of which the member trying to do the submit the form belongs to, I have set everything to "Yes".

My code looks like this

```
{exp:channel:form
channel="orders"
entry_id="{entry_id}"
return="ordre/vis/{url_title}"
  }
 {status_menu}
    <select name="status" class="status">
        {select_options}
    </select>
{/status_menu}

<input type="submit" class="submit-status" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Note that with Super Admin it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If it is guest posting, make sure you've allowed guests to post in the control panel (aside from user permissions).

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/

"Allowing guest posts is controlled in the Channel From settings at Admin ‣ Channel Administration ‣ Channel Form."

Comment: It is not a guest post unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the **Include Members in PUBLISH page multi-author list?** option is set to **Yes** for the member group in question. (This setting may also have been overridden per member as well, under **Member Preferences**).

Comment: That is done, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely zero clue why, but today it suddenly works. Maybe I tried something in my sleep or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is already working for the OP, but one other possibility for future reference is if the status itself is allowed for the member group.  In addition to channel posting permissions, you can also individually control each status' permissions from the Admin > Channel Administration > Statuses > Group Name > Status Name menu.

Note that when a status is marked 'Can access status' = 'No' for a member group, it means that the member group can not select it themselves although an administrator with proper permissions can still set an entry belonging to that restricted member group to the status.  So for example:

- Status name is 'Approved'.  It is marked 'Can access status' = 'No' for member group 'Members' but 'Can access status' = 'Yes' for member group 'Administrators'.
- Member group 'Members' is unable to edit an entry and set it to 'Approved'.
- Member group 'Administrators' is able to edit an entry belonging to 'Members' and set the status to 'Approved'.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as well. Found this old EE1 forum post but the solution worked in EE2 for me: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/54933/

In `exp_members`, the column `in_authorlist`, set all the users that you need to be able to edit to y.

This can also be done in the CP. Edit a users profile and then under Member Preferences, check the box for `Include user in PUBLISH page multi-author list?`.